# Transparent Glass looks grey after saving

Tags: rendering, glass

I'm trying to render transparent glass as png, in render preview looks awesome

[image]

After saving it looks dull and grey

[image]

Any idea why?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit]

Comment: Could you please share your file? If you use an image (like an HDRI image) don't forget to pack before sharing: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I have the same issue. You also have transparent glass checked in film and use an indirect lighting object?